# Firefox browsing history: strange setting behaviour

Tags: firefox, history

I noticed that the location bar in Firefox (3.6) became less responsive the last weeks. I figured it was due to a too large history list, so I decided to make it shorter.

In the privacy options of Firefox there is an entry "Remember my browsing history for at least x days" which defaults to 90 days. However, when I checked my history list, to my surprise there where entries under "history older than 6 months", which is definitely longer than 90 days.

**Question:** Why does it keep history longer than the specified number of days (what's the point otherwise of specifying it)? Related, why does it say "... *at least* x days..."? If I set it to 30 days, I would it expect it to delete history entries as soon as they become 31 days old, not keep them.

(BTW: cleaning the history list solved the location bar sluggishness, but that's not the issue here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking the values for these by typing about:config in your address bar.

```
browser.history_expire_days
```

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.history_expire_days

```
browser.history_expire_days_min
```

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.history_expire_days_min

```
browser.history_expire_sites
```

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.history_expire_sites

Note: Pages expire after X days, but they only do it on shutdown..

This could be a bug. Though there was also a bug earlier, which i think has been resolved.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55293

Comment: Ah, indeed. The `history_expire_days` is set to 180, while the `history_expire_days_min` reflects my (new) dialog box wise setting of 30 days. Very nontransparent and confusing the way they implemented this, if you ask me. The user tells Firefox to keep it for 30 days, but a different alternative setting potentially keeps it longer !

Comment: I've limited `history_expire_sites` to 10 000 as well (was 40 000). Thanks for the tip.

Comment: My Pleasure :) I'm glad you found it useful :)