# What settings are available to make Thunderbird more responsive with large mailboxes?

Tags: thunderbird

I use Thunderbird with two rather large IMAP accounts (one has a total of 30 000 messages across all folders) and for the last month Thunderbird has become a bit slower, not too much but still noticeable, especially when I switch folders.

In reference to an earlier [SuperUser Firefox question](https://superuser.com/questions/325173/firefox-browsing-history-strange-setting-behaviour) about the location bar becoming slower over time (and which was solved with some hidden history `about:config` setting):

Are there any useful (hidden or not) Thunderbird settings to make it more responsive for large accounts and folders (e.g. my 'sent items' and 'archive' folder contain >10000 items)?

Comment: And *why* do you still need the 30 000th e-mail back in time? There is no setting that allows you to *magically* make them shrink; you should archive them outside Thunderbird or you could work yourself towards **0** mails, check out the top two answers on our [Personal Productivity - Inbox Zero](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/318/is-there-a-proven-method-for-managing-emails) question...

Comment: @Tom: edited my question to be more clear that I meant large IMAP accounts and not large folders. Regardless, it's not because my Inbox has zero messages, that my Archive or Sent Items folder is empty...

Comment: An Archive, at least in the context of a e-mail client that does it properly, is not actively loaded but rather on demand. As for the Sent Items; there is again no reason to keep that 30 000th e-mail you sent back in time. A large IMAP account is large folders, it doesn't *magically* make the content to not be on your disk.

Comment: @Tom: gmail (in a browser) *does* manage to load large mailboxes/folders very quickly, and doesn't require me to change my behaviour, delete emails, or look up the apparent definition of Archive. They somehow found an answer to '*magically make them shrink*' My question is: how can I make Thunderbird do this (better).

Comment: If you're using Thunderbird through GMail, its default behavior is to keep most of the messages in memory and to load the headers from Gmail on demand.

Comment: @Rabarberski: You're comparing an optimized big RAID system against your limited personal computer, of course it loads very quickly and doesn't need magical shrinking. Your answer is: You can't make Thunderbird do this better. Don't imagine yourself that there would be an option "shrink everything by 1200%" that they haven't enabled by default. When the bucket is full, you can't fit much more water in it...

Comment: @digitxp: E-mail clients don't keep 30 000 message headers in memory by default; they rather store them and I a lot of content and attachments are stored as well. Unless you are using your e-mail client to never read your e-mails.

Comment: @Tom By memory, I meant local cache. My mistake.